# RBAC within Modules

Tags: module, yii2, rbac

I have an existing Yii2 basic system that runs off an Oracle DB and has RBAC built in via Yii2Admin. It works great.

I have a need now to use another DB (MS-SQL Server 2008) additionally.

So I have set up a new module that uses a second Yii::$app->db2 link and all that is working fine.

My question is, for users of my second MS-SQL Server 2008 DB, is it possible to have logins + RBAC within this module that is linked to the MS-SQL Server 2008 DB rather than the existing Oracle DB.

Or would I have to use Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i think it's possible You can override and create a separate [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html) manager for your MSSQL Server

In the [RBAC DB Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html) you can see property [`db`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html#$db-detail)

in your config file:

```
return [
      // ...
      'components' => [
        'authManager2' => [ // <!-- Auth Manager 2
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'db' => 'db2' // <-- Here is the magic change db instance
      ],
      // ...
],
```

And then you can [build your authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#generating-rbac-data) data using `Yii::$app->authManager2` object

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try folow config.
Fist set MS-SQL Server 2008 connection as db1 name
Example:

```
'db1' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'Your MS-SQL Server 2008  DNS',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

and override function getDB() in ActiveRecord model for db1 value. That will query data from MS-SQL Server 2008.

Document : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#getDb()-detail

Note: You must custom Yii2Admin by extend class or something for work.

Comment: I already have both DB connections working fine.`Note: You must custom Yii2Admin by extend class or something for work.` isn't really an answer to my question

Comment: Are you custome yii2admin module? You net custome function getDb for all model of module